# Upcasting a const vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

Say I have

```
class Parent
{};

class ChildOne : Parent
{};

class ChildTwo : Parent
{};

void SomeMethod(std::vector<Parent*>& parents);
```

I understand why I can't pass a `std::vector<ChildOne*>` as an argument to `SomeMethod` as it's possible that `SomeMethod` may be:

```
void SomeMethod(std::vector<Parent*>& parents)
{
    parents.push_back(new ChildTwo);
}
```

which would be invalid.

But why can't I pass a `std::vector<ChildOne*>` as an argument to

```
void AnotherMethod(const std::vector<Parent*>& parents);
```

In this case I can't think of what could go wrong, but I must be missing something.

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm wondering *why* this restriction exists. In C# (for example), this would compile (with IEnumerables). I assume that there is a failure case that exists.

Comment: There is a serious performance implication in such a conversion, if it would be allowed for convertible types. For pointers, there is no way to assert type safety (i.e. if this feature exists, the conversion `vector<Parent*> -> vector<void*>` would be valid too, as pointers don't know about inheritance. This is a serious mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that it could work *in this particular case* and *on most common platforms.* However, it would be a terrible can of worms to allow this generally.

Consider that the standard doesn't guarantee all data pointers to be of the same size (for example, there are platforms where `char*` is larger than `int*`, because they don't have individually addressible bytes). The fact that you can *convert* a pointer-to-derived into a pointer-to-base does not mean that this conversion is trivial and does not affect the representation in memory. After all, as soon as multiple inheritance enters the picture, even this conversion start to involve *changing the value* of the pointer.

At the same time, templates are quite opaque in general. We know that a sane implementation of `std::vector<T*>` will use the same layout for its data for all `T`s, as long as `T*` are the same size. But in general, a template can do anything based on its template arguments, with totally incompatible data layout.

Not to mention specialisation - if the template was specialised for `<ChildOne*>`, it could be totally incompatible.

Yes, there are cases where a const reference to a *particular implementation* of a template instantiated with `Parent*` could be aliased to the same template instantiated with `ChildOne*`. But these are extremely fragile, and in the general case such substitutability would allow innumerable bugs.

---

If you know that on your platform with your implementation of the standard library and with your types it's safe, you can create a casting function for it:

```
template <class D, class S>
const std::vector<D*>& base_cast(const std::vector<S*> &src)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<D*>&>(src);
}
```

But use at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<ChildOne*>
```

and

```
std::vector<Parent*>
```

are two different/"unrelated" types.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question: Why the implementer of the library had to do so ?

Comment: @hivert Yes, it does answer the question. What do you mean with "implementer of the library"?

Answer (score 0):

Years later, but I found a section of "The c++ Programming Language" that answers this question, section 27.2.1

"Logically, we count treat an immutable `set<Circle*>` as an immutable set because the problem of inserting an inappropriate element into the set cannot occur when we cannot change the set. That is, we could provide a conversion from c`onst set<const Circle*>` to `const set<const Shape*>`. The language doesn't do so by default, but the designer of set could."